# MySQL: How to get the percentage of non existing IDs in a table using only one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, percentage

Actually I am using two queries to get

1. the sum of existing IDs in a table
2. the missing IDs in the same table

then I use PHP to calculate the percentage of the missing IDs in this table.

I am sure there are better ways and I am searching the best one, in example **using only one query** to **directly receive the percentage value** from the mysql query and with the **fastest performance**.

Let's say my table name is `my_table` and the column with the values is named `id`. 
There are only unique ids in the column from 1 to *, and some ids are missing between.
Example rows (values): 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 22, ....

Which mysql query do you think would be the best way to **directly receive the percentage of missing ids** in this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT (MAX(id)-count(id)) / MAX(id) * 100 as MissingRate
    FROM my_table
```

Comment: After your edit, this is giving the correct **missing** percentage, so it's the correct answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the correct percentage. It will calculate it, based that you look every missing number like a missing number.

```
SELECT Count(id)/MAX(id) as percent
    FROM my_table
```